# Multiple plus and minus buttons in a table jquery do not work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html

It is a simple question but I don't know how to fix. I have several rows and for each row there are three elements, minus-button, quantity and plus-button. Everything was ok but when I put the rows inside a table, the buttons don't have effect on the quantity field. Moreover, I'm creating a dynamic table with rails but I just wrote the code that rails generated in HTML. I have tried it and the code is:

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
  if (!isNaN($(this).prev().val()))
    $(this).prev().val(+$(this).prev().val() + 1);
  else
    $(this).prev().val(0);
});
$('.sub').click(function() {
  if ((!isNaN($(this).next().val())) && ($(this).next().val() > 0))
    $(this).next().val(+$(this).next().val() - 1);
  else
    $(this).next().val(0);
});
```

```css
button {
  margin: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input {
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 4px;
  color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button name="button" type="button" class="sub btn btn-default">-</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="quantity" type="text" id="1" value="0" class="field" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button name="button" type="button" class="add btn btn-default">+</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button name="button" type="button" class="sub btn btn-default">-</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="quantity" type="text" id="2" value="0" class="field" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button name="button" type="button" class="add btn btn-default">+</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button name="button" type="button" class="sub btn btn-default">-</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="quantity" type="text" id="1" value="0" class="field" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button name="button" type="button" class="add btn btn-default">+</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button name="button" type="button" class="sub btn btn-default">-</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="quantity" type="text" id="2" value="0" class="field" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button name="button" type="button" class="add btn btn-default">+</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: the .next/.prev calls are kinda pointless. each of the buttons is a single tag inside their table cells, which means there's no siblings, therefore next/prev having nothing to return. I'm guessing you're trying to increment the `quantity` input, so you should be doing something like `$this.parent().find('input[name=quantity]')` or whatever.

Comment: Ok, now the problem is that I need to select specific `quantity` input and with `'input[name=quantity]'` I select all the inputs with name `quantity`. Do you understand me?

Comment: DOM's a tree. every node knows its parents/children, and you can trivially move up/down/sideways, so `$this.parent.next` would take you from button->td(with button)->td(with input), and then it's just a matter of moving "down" a spot to get to the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right Marc B, thanks. I found this solution:

```
$(this).parent().prev().children(".field")
```

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
  if (!isNaN($(this).parent().prev().children(".field").val()))
    $(this).parent().prev().children(".field").val(+$(this).parent().prev().children(".field").val() + 1);
  else
    $(this).parent().prev().children(".field").val(0);
});
$('.sub').click(function() {
  if ((!isNaN($(this).parent().next().children(".field").val())) && ($(this).parent().next().children(".field").val() > 0))
    $(this).parent().next().children(".field").val(+$(this).parent().next().children(".field").val() - 1);
  else
    $(this).parent().next().children(".field").val(0);
});
```

```css
button {
  margin: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input {
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 4px;
  color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button name="button" type="button" class="sub btn btn-default">-</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="quantity" type="text" id="1" value="0" class="field" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button name="button" type="button" class="add btn btn-default">+</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button name="button" type="button" class="sub btn btn-default">-</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="quantity" type="text" id="2" value="0" class="field" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button name="button" type="button" class="add btn btn-default">+</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```